# Query inside Get router in Node Express

Tags: node.js, postgresql

Basically i would like to make a query inside my router each time there is a get request. 
I tried this and some variants

```
var express = require('express');
var router = express.Router();
var pg = require('pg');

router.get('/:listaId', function (req, res, next) {
if (error) return next(error);
var cc = new pg.Client({
    user: "@@",
    password: "@@",
    database: "@@",
    port: 5432,
    host: "@@",
    ssl: true
});
client.connect(function (err) {
    if (err) {
        return console.error('could not connect to postgres', err);
    }
    cc.query('select * from userls', function (err, result1) {

        console.log("Ok", result1.rows, err)

    })
})
res.render('mas', {
    title: 'Lista',
    subtitle: 'CreateBla',
    subs: 'a',
    lev: 's'
})})
```

But the query is never called, basically it goes directly to the rendering.

How can i wait the answer of the query before rendering?
Is it a wrong approach?

Answer (score 1):

> How can i wait the answer of the query before rendering? Is it a wrong
>   approach?

You have to put the `res.render()` inside the query callback where your data is known:

```
var express = require('express');
var router = express.Router();
var pg = require('pg');

router.get('/:listaId', function (req, res, next) {
    if (error) return next(error);
    var cc = new pg.Client({
        user: "@@",
        password: "@@",
        database: "@@",
        port: 5432,
        host: "@@",
        ssl: true
    });
    client.connect(function (err) {
        if (err) {
            return console.error('could not connect to postgres', err);
        }
        cc.query('select * from userls', function (err, result1) {

            console.log("Ok", result1.rows, err)
            res.render('mas', {
                title: 'Lista',
                subtitle: 'CreateBla',
                subs: 'a',
                lev: 's'
            })

        })
    })
})
```

Also, your code looks a little odd that you're using `client` in one place and `cc` in another and you should be checking for errors in your `cc.query()` callback and you presumably want to be using the query results in your render.

Comment: Ok i changed all to client, it was a mistake due to cmd+z, anyway i tried the code and still it never enter inside the query("Ok"), and now it also doesn't render anymore the page...

Comment: Does it even get to the connect callback? Also, you don't actually need to wait for the connect callback before executing the query. See this [example](https://github.com/brianc/node-postgres/wiki/Client#simple-query-with-row-callback)